# Problems to visualize CSS on HTML code

Tags: html, css

The CSS doesn't apply to this code and for a big ironoy in IE i could barely visualize but in the others no, what do you think is happen?

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title father="*head" id="ttl">aadsnfasjnsadgasg</title>
        <link father="*head" href="http://www.bmsuite.com/modules/mika/css/main.css" id="mika_css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body id="body" key="40f8471224aafe869b3e13414c5cb6514dd014d2">
        <DIV class="ui-draggable" id="1div"></DIV>
        <INPUT class="ui-draggable" id="1input"/>
        <LABEL class="ui-draggable" id="1label">Nombre:</LABEL>
    </body>
</html>
```

(This seems to be the CSS)

```
#body{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: silver;
}

#1div{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-image: initial; 
    background-attachment: initial; 
    background-origin: initial; 
    background-clip: initial; 
    background-color: rgb(92, 156, 204); 
    top: -21px; left: 218px; 
    background-position: initial initial; 
    background-repeat: initial initial; 
    :undefined;
}

#1div{
    position: absolute; 
    background-image: initial; 
    background-attachment: initial; 
    background-origin: initial; 
    background-clip: initial; 
    background-color: rgb(92, 156, 204); 
    width: 900px; 
    height: 100%; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 218px; background-position: initial initial; 
    background-repeat: initial initial;
}

#body{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: silver;
}

#1label{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 190px; 
    left: 352px; 
    :undefined;
}

#body{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: silver; 
    :undefined;
}
```

Comment: How does your CSS look like? Is it loaded by the browser? Is the URL correct?

Comment: Check your network connection to http://www.bmsuite.com/modules/mika/css/main.css

Comment: Your CSS contains errors e.g. `:undefined;`.

Comment: I've already fix it and doesn't make any change.

Comment: Everything is correct now and still continue with the same problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs and Classes cannot start with numbers. You need to use the word 'one' instead of '1' if you **must** number the div, input & label. Your current CSS rules will be ignored because they start with a number which is invalid.

Failing that, try changing: `rel="Stylesheet"` to `rel="stylesheet"` some browsers might not like your capitalization of 'stylesheet'.

Also, you define the rules for `#body` three times in your CSS which is pointless. The browser will use whichever rules come last. Also, you should try to combine your rules for `#1div` because most of that is redundant. Many of the rules in this CSS are setting the default values which isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the solution i will implement your advice on the system that generate that CSS and the HTML!!!